# Spring OAuth2 Resource Server Filter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

We are using the `@EnableResourceServer` annotation to apply the security filter for all our APIs. We are using **Spring OAuth2 and JWT tokens**. We use both client credentials token (obtained using client-id and client secret) and User token (using name/password)

We want to protect certain endpoints `(**/clientTokenAllowed/myapi)` using the client JWT token, whereas all others would need a user JWT token.

Where should I put this validation check in the filter? Could not find the right example to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Spring Security OAuth you can make use of expressions like `#oauth2.hasScope()`, `#oauth2.isUser()`, `#oauth2.isClient()` and the likes in your ResourceServer HTTPSecurity configuration. More like these expressions can be found [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/expression/OAuth2SecurityExpressionMethods.html)

So in your case you might want to use `#oauth2.isUser()` and `#oauth2.isClient()`.

Comment: currently is deprecated solution, unfortunately i cannot find any replacement